Fix IO errors during startup - fsck not helping
observe the below error -

How to get past this? Ran fsck -y, fsck -a and fsck -f on nvme0n1p1, nvme0n1p2, etc.
Initially I recall seeing some "ignore error" prompts which were automatically answered with a y. But later runs just succeed.
Yet I am unable to login to my debian system.
EDIT:
Copying out of the partition with dd yielded the below; but running badblocks showed none of it -
dd: error reading '/dev/nvme0n1p3': Input/output error
536299424+414 records in
536299838+0 records out
274585517056 bytes (275 GB, 256 GiB) copied, 7226.72 s, 38.0 MB/s
dd: error reading '/dev/nvme0n1p3': Input/output error
536299424+415 records in
536299839+0 records out
274585517568 bytes (275 GB, 256 GiB) copied, 7226.84 s, 38.0 MB/s
283465585152 bytes (283 GB, 264 GiB) copied, 7615 s, 37.2 MB/s
553647712+416 records in
553648128+0 records out
283467841536 bytes (283 GB, 264 GiB) copied, 7618.66 s, 37.2 MB/s
    ~                                                                                   ✔  2h 6m 59s  
    ~  sudo badblocks -v /dev/nvme0n1p3 > badblocks3.txt                                              ✔ 
Checking blocks 0 to 276824063
Checking for bad blocks (read-only test): 
done                                                 
Pass completed, 0 bad blocks found. (0/0/0 errors)


Maybe try replacing the RAM first. Or if you have more than one bar, use them one after another. Had similar problems a few years ago, and it turned out to be bad memory.

Don't use fsck if you have any data you need recovering from this device. It's dead, and trying to fix it will make things worse

You have a hardware failure: as the messages tell you, there is an I/O error (very many, actually) when interacting with your nvme device. You are seeing "critical medium errors": the storage medium is damaged.
You can't fix that with fsck – fsck restores data structures, but you have broken hardware.
The only way out here is replacing your NVMe SSD. It is broken.
